# firemonkey convert mp3 stream to hex and reverse

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

i try to save a audio from mobile microphone to a Tmemorystream and then convert it to hex with this function:

```
function StreamToHexStr(AStream: TStream): string;
const
 HexArr: array[0..15] of char =
 ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F');
var
 AByte: Byte;
 i: Integer;
begin
 SetLength(Result, AStream.Size * 2);
 AStream.Position := 0;
 for i := 0 to AStream.Size - 1 do
 begin
   AStream.ReadBuffer(AByte, SizeOf(AByte));
   Result[i * 2 + 1] := HexArr[AByte shr 4];
   Result[i * 2 + 2] := HexArr[AByte and $0F];
 end;
end;
```

the output is a hexadecimal string

after transfer it a a second device i have to change the hex code to a Tmemorystream and the play it with this function:

```
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create(Stream);
  try
    Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ReciavedSTR));
  finally
    Writer.Free;
  end;
  Stream.SaveToFile( TPath.GetSharedMoviesPath()+'/record2.mp3' );
```

but the `record2.mp3` is not playable and it just include the converted hex string

what is wrong with my code?

for a simple test when i save the recorded stream to a file with this code

```
FOutputStream.SaveToFile( TPath.GetSharedMoviesPath()+'/record.mp3' );
```

it working good.

update project concept:

[image]
the hardware transmitter get 406 hex char from mobile phone on serial port and transfer it to second device,then the receiver deliver the hex string to second mobile phone , the second phone must join the strings and convert them to a hear-able sound.

a sample output of base64 to stream and stream save to file

[sample mp3 file](https://bazmineh.com/record2.mp3)

Comment: Your forward and reverse functions bear no resemblance to each other, so of course it will not work. What makes you imagine that UTF8 is related to the hexadecimal representation of a binary stream?

Comment: Most likely, you don't convert the hex string back to binary. Not sure why you convert the binary to a hex string in the first place.

Comment: @Dsm is thre a way to convert the stream ?! i used `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes` the convert string to byte

Comment: Why would you want to encode a binary file as a hex string? Why choose base16? If you have to transmit as text then isn't base 64 more efficient. But still, isn't binary even more efficient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i must send data in 203 byte hex chunks with serial port to a radio transmitter.this is a role of the project (it must to encode in a hardware transmitter),however i can encode data to base64 but still the problem is convert back the string to a mp3 stream  !?

Comment: Well, of course you can convert to and from base64. 203 byte hex makes no sense. Hex strings would be even lengths.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  i mean 203*2 chars.how can i convert hex to mp3 stream or a mp3 file to play with media player ?!

Comment: I still don't see any reason why you'd encode as base16

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't just send the file as it is.  If there is hardware on the other end, is it running Delphi and is the receiver running this Delphi code to translate the hex string back to a binary representation, or are you only trying to do this to test whether you've correctly encoded the string in the first place?  If the latter case, is the receiving hardware simply a black box which receives MP3 files as hex strings in 203 byte blocks?  It's really not clear why you're trying to do it this way... this seems like a demented way to transfer a binary file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as i said base16 or base64 not important,it must be a string without any special chars!!

Comment: Take a look at the `System.NetEncoding` unit. It includes both ways conversion for various encodings.

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes the `EncodeBase64` working good but the output of `DecodeBase64` is system.Tarray and the problem is how to convert system.Tarray to mp3 stream :)

Comment: Look closer at the `TNetEncoding` class. It has several overloaded versions of `encode()` and `decode()` methods, also with `TStream` as both input and output.

Comment: Com ports can send bytes.  Why do you not want to send the binary data?  Do you (incorrectly) believe that com ports can only transmit strings?  Is this solution based on that misunderstanding?  What is this "transmitter"?  Did you build it?  Is it a commercial device?  With an API?

Comment: i know com port can transfer binary, the hardware encryptor just accept string data.transmitter is a fpga based that build by our team.

Comment: @peimanF. NO MATTER HOW you decide to *encode* the data at the transmitter layer, the receiver layer must *decode* using the SAME format.  In your original code, you *encode* to a hex-formatted string, but *decode* that string as if it were UTF-8 bytes instead. That is a clear mismatch in formats. You need to *decode* the received string as a hex string in order to get back the original bytes (ie, for every 2-char pair in the string, convert each char to the corresponding 4 bits, and then merge the 2 sets of bits together into a single byte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, let me answer your initial question

### How to convert a stream to and from base16 (aka ASCII-HEX).

Your code to convert to base16 is correct, here is an essentially equal version:

```
function StreamToHexStr(const AStream: TStream): String;
const
  cMap : array[0..15] of Char = (
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
var
  lData: Byte;
  lPos: Integer;
begin
  Setlength(Result, AStream.Size * 2);
  AStream.Position := 0; 
  lPos := Low(Result);
  while AStream.ReadData(lData) = sizeof(lData) do begin
    Result[lPos]     := cMap[lData shr 4];
    Result[lPos + 1] := cMap[lData and $0F];
    Inc(lPos, 2);
  end;
end;
```

To convert the string back into a stream, try this:

```
procedure HexStrToStream(const AString: String; AStream: TStream);
const
  // Mapping vom ASCII-Code to value
  cMap: array['0'..'F'] of Byte  = (
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  // $30..$39 / '0'..'9'
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, //  $3A..$40
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15); // $41..$46 / 'A'..'F'
var
  lPos: Integer;
begin
  lPos := Low(AString);
  while lPos < High(AString) do begin
    AStream.WriteData(UInt8(cMap[AString[lPos]] shl 4 + cMap[AString[lPos + 1]]));
    Inc(lPos, 2);
  end;
end;
```

To use this code simply do:

```
Base16String := StreamToHexStr(MP3Stream);
```

on the sender and on the receiver do:

```
lRecvStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
try
  HexStrToStream(Base16RecvString, RecvStream);
  lRecvStream.SaveToFile('Record.mp3');
finally
  lRecvStream.Free();
end;
```

### How to do the same for base64

With a TMemoryStream on the sending side you simply do:

```
lString := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(lInStream.Memory, lInStream.Size);
```

and on the receiving side you use a TBytesStream (which is a descendant of a TMemoryStream):

```
lRecvStream := TBytesStream.Create(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(lString));
try
  lRecvStream.SaveToFile('Record.mp3');
finally
  lRecvStream.Free();
end;
```

### Things you may consider

During the transfer of the data, some bytes may be changed or get lost. Sometimes whole packets will not be received. Depending on your requirements, your application may need some protection against such errors.

Comment: i tested base16 and it working good.about data lost we do C0 slip for error detection at this time.thank you..